# how to bottom align div using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I have `div` which have some text content. I want to make that div  align to bottom . or in other words it bottom never change when text grow .

here is my code

https://codepen.io/naveen-1234/pen/ExXNRbZ

**when I have small text it looks good**
[image]

**but when my text increase it overflow the container like this**

[image]

but **the expected output is it should grow in upward direction**

**Expected output**

[image]

**is there any way in css grid using `minmaxval` or auto-fit or auto fill to grow div in upward direction** .?

```
.abc{
  display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12,6.697%);
    grid-template-rows: 18px repeat(4, 1fr);
   border:1px solid green;
  height:320px
}
.one{
  grid-column: 2/5;
   grid-row: 3/5;
    border:1px solid;
}
.two {
  grid-row: 1/5;
    border:1px solid #ee0;
}


<div class="abc">
  
  <div class="one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates culpa iste facaudantium Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates culpa iste facaudantium
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates culpa iste facaudantium
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates culpa iste facaudantium</p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    tooo
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you check my solution?

Comment: @SachinAnanthakumar there is no need to ask to check your solution. If you answer the user will get a notification.

Comment: @GertB. got it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for. as far as my understanding the requirements are for the container to start **from the end of the todo** container and **grow upwards**, this css fulfills the requirements

```
.abc{
  display:grid;
height:auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12,6.697%);
    grid-template-rows: 18px repeat(4, 1fr);
   border:1px solid green;
  /* height:320px */
}
.one{
  grid-column: 2/5;

  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
    border:1px solid;
  display: flex;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color:red;
  justify-content: center;

}
.two {
  grid-row: 1/5;
    border:1px solid #ee0;
}
```

Comment: this solution is good, but without height it will make container "abc" growing to fast depends on text content, and with height it will overflow

Answer (score 1):

Add this changes:

```
.abc{
  height: auto;
}
.one{
  grid-row: 1/5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: not a correct solution share codepen link

Comment: @user5711656  https://codepen.io/Zerhogi/pen/dyROjbj in this codepen I've used height 560px just to show that text is growing up, but you need set it ot auto to prevent overflowing

Comment: thanks for answer. but why you change `grid-row: 2/5;` ---> `grid-row: 1/5;` ??? by default it should be `grid-row: 2/5;` but when text grow then only it grows to top

Comment: i changed it because in your expected behavior black bordered box height = yellow box height

Comment: @user5711656 check my solution

Comment: @Zerhogi Checkout my solution